# Date comparison in where clause does not work as expected

Tags: php, sql

I have a table as follows:
[image]

Now I want to count rows where ship_date is past date. And I am trying as follows:

```
 $today = date('yy-m-d');
 $sql = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM spot_shipment_order where date('ship_date') < '$today'";
```

Today's date is: 2020-04-27 and final SQL is:
`SELECT count(*) as total FROM spot_shipment_order where date('ship_date') < '2020-04-27'.` As 2020-04-29 is not past date with respect to today's date, hence the above SQL should count 0. it returns 1. Strange!. this problem make me cry. I think I am doing some mistakes and can't explore that mistake. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't put single quotes around `ship_date`.  And just use `CURRENT_DATE` in the database (or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` depending on what you really mean).

Comment: Interesting that `'ship_date'` did not throw errors. Use backticks not quotes

Comment: Also what is the data-type for ship_date? DATE i hope

Comment: `date('yy-m-d');` this will only work for this year. Next year it will show 2121. You'd want `Y-m-d` for the properly formatted 2020-04-27.

Comment: How are you checking for the count after you run this query? If you're using num_rows, then yes, it will always return 1 because it's returning a count.

Comment: Yes, ship_date is date type

Comment: no need to add date(_) in quuery just where ship_date  < '$today'";

Comment: Thanks everyone. I changed single quotes into backticks and it works.